# VBA macro for Excel to only read Part of a barcode

Tags: excel, barcode, vba

I am using the following VBA code in Excel to read the input from a barcode scanner and search an existing column (C) for a matching value.  The barcodes that I am scanning have some "extra" characters at the end (after a space) that I don't want to have scanned or at least not searched for against the values in column C.  Is there a way I can have the barcode reader ignore the characters after the space or limit the scan to the first X characters, etc?

```
Sub DataInput()
    Dim SearchTarget As String
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Static PrevCell As Range
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim CurCell As Range


10  'SearchTarget = "qwer"
    SearchTarget = InputBox("Scan or type product barcode...", "Scan Barcode")

    If SearchTarget = "" Then GoTo 30

    If PrevCell Is Nothing Then
        myRow = Selection.Row
        Set PrevCell = Range("C" & myRow)
    End If


    Set Rng = Range("C:C,C:C") 'Columns for search defined here
    With Rng
        Set FoundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=SearchTarget, _
        After:=PrevCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
    End With

    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "These are not the Droids you are looking for"

    Else
        FoundCell.Activate
        '        If PrevCell.Address = FoundCell.Address Then
        '            MsgBox "found a match!"
        '        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        timestamp = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy hh:mm")
        ActiveCell = timestamp
        ActiveCell = Now()

        MsgBox "FOUND IT!!  SEND TO LES"
        ' Found.Show
        If Found.CommandButton1 Then GoTo 20

        Set PrevCell = FoundCell
    End If
20  GoTo 10


30  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the left() command to use only the first x characters of a string. Something like:

```
TrimmedBarcode = left(UntrimmedBarcode, x)
```

Where TrimmedBarcode is where you'll store the shortened barcode, UntrimmedBarcode is the input from the scanner and x is the number of characters you need.

EDIT: With your variables,

```
SearchTarget = Left(InputBox("Scan or type product barcode...", "Scan Barcode"), 6)
```

Adjust 6 to whatever number of characters you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Split` function --- it will split a string on a char you specify and return an array containing the split up string. For example

```
SplitString = Split(MyString, " ")
```

will split a string anywhere a space occurs. If you want everything that precedes the first space you can use this

```
LeftOfFirstSpace = Split(Barcode, " ")(0)
```

You can also use the `InStr` function to search within a string.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!  I found both of these methods would work but for my application have decided on the Left function because have determined in my application, the first 8 characters of the barcode should always be the value I'm searching for.